# Array whose first element is arbitralily indexed – writing a container wrapper

Tags: c++, collections, wrapper

### The problem:

In C++ arrays and SequenceContainers http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer (`std::array`, `std::deque`, `std::vector`) are necessarily zero-indexed. However, from the semantical point of view, elements of an array may be assigned a completely other range of indexes. One common example is the need to store a 1-indexed array in a 0-indexed container. (I remember having to operate on an arbitrarily-indexed arrays, however)

Solutions to the above problems include:

- remembering to skew the index by a given constant each time such an array is indexed – this leads to lots of code like `vec[n-1]` or sth like that – but this approach is tedious and error-prone (it’s easy to forget this `-1` and instead type `vec[n]`, oops);
- Defining a class for such an array that would have a method like `some_type &operator [] (unsigned n) {return m_arr[n-1];}` – but this can often be quite overkillish;
- The crude approach: Forget about the fact that arrays are 0-indexed; treat them as if they were 1-indexed and never use index 0. This approach is, however, well – crude, and it will fail with arbitrarily-indexed arrays.

### The proposed solution:

I thought I’d write a wrapper for SequenceContainers that would differ from standard containers only in that its `operator[]` and the `at` functions would skew their arguments by a given offset. I wrote two versions of this wrapper: one, when the offset is determined compile-time as a template argument, and the other one, when it can be modified run-time. I believe that both are needed.

The usage is simple, as shown in a trivial example of calculating lengths of Collatz sequence for the first 100 initial values: ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture ) (sorry for the naive algorithm)

```
#include "shiftsc.hpp"

using namespace std;

using element = unsigned;
using length = unsigned;

length compute_length(element n)
  {return n == 1 ? 1 : (1 + compute_length(n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : n * 3 + 1));}

int main()
{
  constexpr element max_element = 100;

  // one-indexed std::array<length, max_element>
  shifted_SequenceContainer<array<length, max_element>, 1> Collatz_lengths;
  // or for short: shifted_array<length, max_element, 1> Collatz_lengths;

  for(element i = 1; i <= max_element; i++)
    Collatz_lengths[i] = compute_length(i);
}
```

Seen working: http://ideone.com/Xy8A2U

(I’ll provide a use-case for the variation with run-time offset later, in a separate question – I have an idea for yet another wrapper that would need this functionality to operate)

### The problems with the solution:

Before I present You the code, I have to write down a few issues I can see with this code I don’t know how to fix… (inb4 close votes: they don’t make the code broken!)

- The length of the code. Ikr, it is hilarious. There’s very little I can do, however: writing containers requires defining a TON of different methods, and although the code of most of them is *trivial*, their sheer amount is what makes this code 453 lines long. I thought about different ‘solutions” to this issue, none of which worked: • defining a base class for container wrappers – impossible b/c of the incompatibility of `virtual` with templates (couldn’t allow overloading methods like `template <class Iterator> void assign (Iterator it, Iterator jt)`; • defining repetitive methods and the whole class in terms of macros; this did work and did shorten the code, but IMO made it utterly unreadable, so I gave up.
- `std::array` can be initialized with a braced-init-list; unfortunately, `shifted_SequenceContainer<std::array</*...*/>/*...*/>` cannot. And I don’t really have many ideas how to fix this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599052/how-to-write-a-wrapper-for-stdarrays-list-initialization-constructor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599829/how-to-pass-a-braced-init-list-to-stdarray-s-constructor
- The naming. Ikr, `shifted_SequenceContainer` breaks all naming conventions… But what can I do? The concept is called `SequenceContainer`, so if I changed that, I’d cease referring to this concept… It’s called `SequenceContainer` not `sequence_container` so a name like `shifted_sequence_container` won’t fit, and a name like `ShiftedSequenceContainer` would be incongruent with the naming of standard containers – after all, `std::unordered_map` is called `unordered_map` and not `UnorderedMap`.

### The code:

Enough of the (lengthy) preface, here comes the actual code:

```
#ifndef GAAZKAM_SHIFTSC_H
#define GAAZKAM_SHIFTSC_H

#include <utility>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

// Known problems: syntax like shifted_array<int, 4, 7> arr({1,2,3,4}) wont work

// With static offset

// Container must satisfy SequenceContainer
template<class Container, typename Container::difference_type Offset>
class shifted_SequenceContainer
{
public:
  using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
  using reference = typename Container::reference;
  using const_reference = typename Container::const_reference;
  using pointer = typename Container::pointer;
  using const_pointer = typename Container::const_pointer;
  using iterator = typename Container::iterator;
  using const_iterator = typename Container::const_iterator;
  using reverse_iterator = typename Container::reverse_iterator;
  using const_reverse_iterator = typename Container::const_reverse_iterator;
  using difference_type = typename Container::difference_type;
  using size_type = typename Container::size_type;

  using container_type = Container;

  // Must be public; otherwise the user mayn’t access e.g. vector::reserve,
  // which might be needed for optimization
  Container cont;

  static constexpr typename Container::difference_type offset = Offset;

  explicit shifted_SequenceContainer() {}
  shifted_SequenceContainer(shifted_SequenceContainer const &that)
    : cont(that.cont) {}
  shifted_SequenceContainer(shifted_SequenceContainer &&that)
    : cont(std::move(that.cont)) {}
  explicit shifted_SequenceContainer(Container const &that) : cont(that) {}
  explicit shifted_SequenceContainer(Container &&that) : cont(that) {}
  shifted_SequenceContainer &operator = (shifted_SequenceContainer const &that)
    {cont = that.cont; return *this;}
  shifted_SequenceContainer &operator = (shifted_SequenceContainer &&that)
    {cont = std::move(that.cont); return *this;}
  shifted_SequenceContainer &operator = (Container const &that)
    {cont = that; return *this;}
  shifted_SequenceContainer &operator = (Container &&that)
    {cont = std::move(that); return *this;}
  shifted_SequenceContainer
    (size_type n, value_type const &val = value_type())
    : cont(n, val) {}
  template<class Iterator> shifted_SequenceContainer(Iterator it, Iterator jt)
    : cont(it, jt) {}
  shifted_SequenceContainer(std::initializer_list<value_type> init) 
    : cont(init) {}
  shifted_SequenceContainer &operator = (std::initializer_list<value_type> init)
    {cont = init; return *this;}
  void assign(size_type n, value_type const &val) {return cont.assign(n, val);}
  template<class Iterator> void assign(Iterator it, Iterator jt)
    {return cont.assign(it, jt);}
  void assign(std::initializer_list<value_type> init)
    {return cont.assign(init);}
  void swap(shifted_SequenceContainer &that) {return cont.swap(that.cont);}
  friend void swap
    (shifted_SequenceContainer &lhs, shifted_SequenceContainer &rhs)
    {return swap(lhs.cont, rhs.cont);}

  friend bool operator ==
    (shifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs, shifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs)
    {return lhs.cont == rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator != 
    (shifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs, shifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs)
    {return lhs.cont != rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator <
    (shifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs, shifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs)
    {return lhs.cont < rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator <=
    (shifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs, shifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs)
    {return lhs.cont <= rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator >
    (shifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs, shifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs)
    {return lhs.cont > rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator >=
    (shifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs, shifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs)
    {return lhs.cont >= rhs.cont;}

  constexpr size_type size() const {return cont.size();}
  constexpr size_type max_size() const {return cont.max_size();}
  void resize(size_type n) {return cont.resize(n);}
  void resize(size_type n, value_type const &val) {return cont.resize(n, val);}
  constexpr bool empty() const {return cont.empty();} 

  template<class ...Args> iterator emplace(const_iterator pos, Args &&...args)
    {return cont.emplace(pos, std::move(args...));}
  template<class ...Args> void emplace_front(Args &&...args)
    {return cont.emplace_front(std::move(args...));}
  template<class ...Args> void emplace_back(Args &&...args)
    {return cont.emplace_back(std::move(args...));}
  iterator insert(const_iterator pos, value_type const &val)
    {return cont.insert(pos, val);}
  iterator insert(const_iterator pos, value_type &&val)
    {return cont.insert(pos, std::move(val));}
  iterator insert(const_iterator pos, size_type n, value_type const &val)
    {return cont.insert(pos, n, val);}
  template<class Iterator> void insert(iterator pos, Iterator it, Iterator jt)
    {return cont.insert(pos, it, jt);}
  iterator insert(const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<value_type> init)
    {return cont.insert(pos, init);}
  void push_front(value_type const &val) {return cont.push_front(val);}
  void push_front(value_type &&val) {return cont.push_front(std::move(val));}
  void push_back(value_type const &val) {return cont.push_back(val);}
  void push_back(value_type &&val) {return cont.push_back(std::move(val));}

  void clear() {return cont.clear();}
  iterator erase(const_iterator pos) {return cont.erase(pos);}
  iterator erase(const_iterator it, const_iterator jt)
    {return cont.erase(it, jt);}
  void pop_front() {return cont.pop_front();}
  void pop_back() {return cont.pop_back();}

  iterator begin() {return cont.begin();}
  constexpr const_iterator begin() const {return cont.begin();}  
  constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const {return cont.cbegin();}
  iterator end() {return cont.end();}
  constexpr const_iterator end() const {return cont.end();}
  constexpr const_iterator cend() const {return cont.cend();}
  reverse_iterator rbegin() {return cont.rbegin();}
  constexpr const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const {return cont.rbegin();}
  constexpr const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const {return cont.crbegin();}
  reverse_iterator rend() {return cont.rend();}
  constexpr const_reverse_iterator rend() const {return cont.rend();}
  constexpr const_reverse_iterator crend() const {return cont.crend();}
  reference front() {return cont.front();}
  constexpr const_reference front() const {return cont.front();}
  reference back() {return cont.back();}
  constexpr const_reference back() const {return cont.back();}

  // Here things actually start to change
  reference operator[] (difference_type pos)
    {return cont.operator[](pos-offset);}
  constexpr const_reference operator[] (difference_type pos) const
    {return cont.operator[](pos-offset);}
  reference at (difference_type pos)
    {if(pos-offset<0) throw std::out_of_range(""); return cont.at(pos-offset);}
  constexpr const_reference at (difference_type pos) const
    {if(pos-offset<0) throw std::out_of_range(""); return cont.at(pos-offset);}

  // Additionally let’s provide these ones:
  iterator find(difference_type pos)
    {return cont.begin()+(pos-offset);}
  constexpr const_iterator find(difference_type pos) const
    {return cont.cbegin()+(pos-offset);}
};

template
  <class T, std::size_t N, typename std::array<T, N>::difference_type offset>
using shifted_array = shifted_SequenceContainer<std::array<T, N>, offset>;

template<class T, typename std::vector<T>::difference_type offset>
using shifted_vector = shifted_SequenceContainer<std::vector<T>, offset>;

template<class T, typename std::deque<T>::difference_type offset>
using shifted_deque = shifted_SequenceContainer<std::deque<T>, offset>;

// With dynamic offset

// Container must satisfy SequenceContainer
template<class Container>
class dynshifted_SequenceContainer
{
public:
  using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
  using reference = typename Container::reference;
  using const_reference = typename Container::const_reference;
  using pointer = typename Container::pointer;
  using const_pointer = typename Container::const_pointer;
  using iterator = typename Container::iterator;
  using const_iterator = typename Container::const_iterator;
  using reverse_iterator = typename Container::reverse_iterator;
  using const_reverse_iterator = typename Container::const_reverse_iterator;
  using difference_type = typename Container::difference_type;
  using size_type = typename Container::size_type;

  using container_type = Container;

  // Must be public; otherwise the user mayn’t access e.g. vector::reserve,
  // which might be needed for optimization
  Container cont;
  difference_type offset = 0;

  explicit dynshifted_SequenceContainer() {}
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer(dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &that)
    : cont(that.cont), offset(that.offset) {}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer
    (shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &that)
    : cont(that.cont), offset(StaticOffset) {}
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer(dynshifted_SequenceContainer &&that)
    : cont(std::move(that.cont)), offset(that.offset) {}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer
    (shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> &&that)
    : cont(std::move(that.cont)), offset(StaticOffset) {}
  explicit dynshifted_SequenceContainer
    (Container const &that, difference_type off = difference_type{}) 
    : cont(that), offset(off) {}
  explicit dynshifted_SequenceContainer
    (Container &&that, difference_type off = difference_type{})
    : cont(that), offset(off) {}
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer &operator =
    (dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &that)
    {offset = that.offset; cont = that.cont; return *this;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer &operator =
    (shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &that)
    {cont = that.cont; offset = StaticOffset; return *this;}
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer &operator = (dynshifted_SequenceContainer &&that)
    {offset = that.offset; cont = std::move(that.cont); return *this;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer &operator = 
    (shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> &&that)
    {{cont = std::move(that.cont); offset = StaticOffset; return *this;}}
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer &operator = (Container const &that)
    {cont = that; return *this;}
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer &operator = (Container &&that)
    {cont = std::move(that); return *this;}
  explicit dynshifted_SequenceContainer
  (
    size_type n,
    value_type const &val = value_type(),
    difference_type offset = 0
  )
    : cont(n, val), offset(offset) {}
  explicit dynshifted_SequenceContainer(size_type n, difference_type offset)
    : cont(n, value_type{}), offset(offset) {}
  template<class Iterator> dynshifted_SequenceContainer
    (Iterator it, Iterator jt, difference_type offset = 0)
    : cont(it, jt), offset(offset) {}
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer
    (std::initializer_list<value_type> init, difference_type offset = 0)
    : cont(init) {}
  dynshifted_SequenceContainer &operator =
    (std::initializer_list<value_type> init)
    {cont = init; return *this;}
  void assign(size_type n, value_type const &val) {return cont.assign(n, val);}
  void assign(size_type n, value_type const &val, difference_type offset)
    {this->offset = offset; return cont.assign(n, val);}
  template<class Iterator> void assign(Iterator it, Iterator jt)
    {return cont.assign(it, jt);}
  template<class Iterator>
  void assign(Iterator it, Iterator jt, difference_type offset)
    {this.offset = offset; return cont.assign(it, jt);}
  void assign(std::initializer_list<value_type> init)
    {return cont.assign(init);}
  void assign(std::initializer_list<value_type> init, difference_type offset)
    {this.offset = offset; return cont.assign(init);}
  void swap(dynshifted_SequenceContainer &that)
    {std::swap(this->offset, that.offset); return cont.swap(that.cont);}
  friend void swap
    (dynshifted_SequenceContainer &lhs, dynshifted_SequenceContainer &rhs)
    {std::swap(lhs.offset, rhs.offset); return swap(lhs.cont, rhs.cont);}

  // I provide all those overloads despite the implicit conversion for
  // optimisation: implicit conversion is always linear, while those
  // overloads may sometimes evaluate in constant
  friend bool operator ==
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.cont == rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator ==
  (
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return StaticOffset == rhs.offset && lhs.cont == rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator ==
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.offset == StaticOffset && lhs.cont == rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator != 
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.cont != rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator !=
  (
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return StaticOffset != rhs.offset || lhs.cont != rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator !=
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.offset != StaticOffset || lhs.cont != rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator < 
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.cont < rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator <
  (
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return StaticOffset < rhs.offset || lhs.cont < rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator <
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.offset < StaticOffset || lhs.cont < rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator <= 
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.cont <= rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator <=
  (
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return StaticOffset <= rhs.offset || lhs.cont <= rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator <=
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.offset <= StaticOffset || lhs.cont <= rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator > 
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.cont > rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator >
  (
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return StaticOffset > rhs.offset || lhs.cont > rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator >
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.offset > StaticOffset || lhs.cont > rhs.cont;}
  friend bool operator >= 
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.cont >= rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator >=
  (
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &lhs,
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &rhs
  )
    {return StaticOffset >= rhs.offset || lhs.cont >= rhs.cont;}
  template<typename Container::difference_type StaticOffset>
  friend bool operator >=
  (
    dynshifted_SequenceContainer const &lhs,
    shifted_SequenceContainer<Container, StaticOffset> const &rhs
  )
    {return lhs.offset >= StaticOffset || lhs.cont >= rhs.cont;}


  constexpr size_type size() const {return cont.size();}
  constexpr size_type max_size() const {return cont.max_size();}
  void resize(size_type n) {return cont.resize(n);}
  void resize(size_type n, value_type const &val) {return cont.resize(n, val);}
  constexpr bool empty() const {return cont.empty();} 

  template<class ...Args> iterator emplace(const_iterator pos, Args &&...args)
    {return cont.emplace(pos, std::move(args...));}
  template<class ...Args> void emplace_front(Args &&...args)
    {return cont.emplace_front(std::move(args...));}
  template<class ...Args> void emplace_back(Args &&...args)
    {return cont.emplace_back(std::move(args...));}
  iterator insert(const_iterator pos, value_type const &val)
    {return cont.insert(pos, val);}
  iterator insert(const_iterator pos, value_type &&val)
    {return cont.insert(pos, std::move(val));}
  iterator insert(const_iterator pos, size_type n, value_type const &val)
    {return cont.insert(pos, n, val);}
  template<class Iterator> void insert(iterator pos, Iterator it, Iterator jt)
    {return cont.insert(pos, it, jt);}
  iterator insert(const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<value_type> init)
    {return cont.insert(pos, init);}
  void push_front(value_type const &val) {return cont.push_front(val);}
  void push_front(value_type &&val) {return cont.push_front(std::move(val));}
  void push_back(value_type const &val) {return cont.push_back(val);}
  void push_back(value_type &&val) {return cont.push_back(std::move(val));}

  void clear() {return cont.clear();}
  iterator erase(const_iterator pos) {return cont.erase(pos);}
  iterator erase(const_iterator it, const_iterator jt)
    {return cont.erase(it, jt);}
  void pop_front() {return cont.pop_front();}
  void pop_back() {return cont.pop_back();}

  iterator begin() {return cont.begin();}
  constexpr const_iterator begin() const {return cont.begin();}  
  constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const {return cont.cbegin();}
  iterator end() {return cont.end();}
  constexpr const_iterator end() const {return cont.end();}
  constexpr const_iterator cend() const {return cont.cend();}
  reverse_iterator rbegin() {return cont.rbegin();}
  constexpr const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const {return cont.rbegin();}
  constexpr const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const {return cont.crbegin();}
  reverse_iterator rend() {return cont.rend();}
  constexpr const_reverse_iterator rend() const {return cont.rend();}
  constexpr const_reverse_iterator crend() const {return cont.crend();}
  reference front() {return cont.front();}
  constexpr const_reference front() const {return cont.front();}
  reference back() {return cont.back();}
  constexpr const_reference back() const {return cont.back();}
  reference operator[] (difference_type pos)
    {return cont.operator[](pos-offset);}
  constexpr const_reference operator[] (difference_type pos) const
    {return cont.operator[](pos-offset);}
  reference at (difference_type pos)
    {if(pos-offset<0) throw std::out_of_range(""); return cont.at(pos-offset);}
  constexpr const_reference at (difference_type pos) const
    {if(pos-offset<0) throw std::out_of_range(""); return cont.at(pos-offset);}
  iterator find(difference_type pos)
    {return cont.begin()+(pos-offset);}
  constexpr const_iterator find(difference_type pos) const
    {return cont.cbegin()+(pos-offset);}
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
using dynshifted_array = dynshifted_SequenceContainer<std::array<T, N>>;

template<class T>
using dynshifted_vector = dynshifted_SequenceContainer<std::vector<T>>;

template<class T>
using dynshifted_deque = dynshifted_SequenceContainer<std::deque<T>>;

#endif
```

I’m doing this hobbystically, and I’m quite much of a greenhorn with programming, so I’d *highly* appreciate any comments. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To quote Stanford algorithm's expert Donald Knuth, ["*Who are you? How did you get in my house?*"](https://xkcd.com/163/)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you are expending way too much energy trying to solve something that should be a non-problem. Simply always let your containers be zero based, if you have for example 1-based indexes as input, simply subtract 1 from them as soon as you get the input and convert back right before output. Always use zero-based indexes internally and only convert as close to input/output as possible.

(too large for comment really)

Comment: If this was for a one-time use, then yes, I agree: this would be an extreme overkill. But, it’s a one-time write. I expend so much energy to write this this time – and I have a more convenient container for the rest of my life. Is it such a bad idea?

Comment: Plus, this (alongside with `asInt`) is just one of quite a lot ideas I have to include in a purely hobbystically written and completely non-production “library” of wrappers and data structures to ease solving `uva.onlinejudge.org` tasks… The idea comes from the fact how I noticed much of my code in these tasks was repetitive and not very neat… so I thought I’d write a bunch of helpers to neaten these codes

Comment: You are of course free to do as you please, but in my 10+ years of solving online judge type problems and in my life as a professional software engineer, I have never had use for such a container. In fact including such code would take more time than to adjust the values when I read them in. Because `#include <whatever.hpp` is simply more text than `-1` once when I read in the value.